# Is cloudshell machine type the same across GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

Pardon me, I'm a new learner and have a lot of newbie questions.

I couldn't find the information on cloudshell's machine type on Google's official documentation. On my end, I have e2-standard-2 as the machine type.

Is e2-standard-2 the provisioned machine type across the board for GCP's cloudshell?

Comment: Before (in 2020 I think), Cloud Shell VM was a `g1-small` and this was stated in the docs (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50022291). Boost mode (now removed) would upgrade the VM to `n1-standard-1`. But as of now, the documentation does not show which machine type this is. I've tried on my Cloud Shell (`wget -q -O - --header Metadata-Flavor:Google metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/machine-type`) and got `projects/<project_id>/machineTypes/e2-standard-4`. How did you get the machine type of your Cloud Shell ?

Comment: Thanks @norbjd! Interesting! I use this ```curl -s http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/machine-type -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"```

Comment: Are you using Google free trial ? This may explain the difference.

Comment: @norbjd yes i am using the free trial. so that means the machine type for free trial is e2-standard-2 while paid account is provisioned e2-standard-4 across the board?  Does GCP provision different machine types for cloudshell based on regions?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is just a guess we can make. And I don't think that machine type depends on region.

Comment: @norbjd it will be interesting if more people can share what their cloud shell machine type is here and we maybe able to have a better idea

Comment: e2-standard-4 - ORG, Paid Account.

Comment: I have e2-standard-4 on a paid account.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @norbjd, the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/how-cloud-shell-works) doesn't specify the exact machine type of the Cloud Shell:

> When you start Cloud Shell, it provisions a Google Compute Engine
> virtual machine running a Debian-based Linux operating system.

You can verify the machine type by running either of two commands in Cloud Shell:

- `wget -q -O - --header Metadata-Flavor:Google metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/machine-type`
- `curl -s http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/machine-type -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"` provided by @PlainH2O.

Based on additional information povided by @JohnHanley, @PlainH2O and @norbjd, we can assume that free trial accounts are provisioned with `e2-standard-2` while paid account are provisioned with `e2-standard-4`.

Comment: It seems like it but not enough data to conclude it.